# Pass handled errors back through Spring Cloud Gateway filters

Tags: error-handling, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a SCG app with a few filters to separately log request metadata, response metadata, and event metadata (e.g. total duration between request sent and the response received). Currently, whenever the app hits a hard 500 error while trying to communicate with a downstream service, it will exit the filter chain entirely. These are any communication exceptions like UnknownHost, ConnectionReset, and the like. As a result, request logging will still work as that is a pre-filter, but the response and event logging won't trigger.

I have configured an ErrorAttributes bean and over-ridden the `logError` method of the DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler and am happy with the way error responses are returned to anyone calling the application. However, I would like to see this error response sent back up through the configured filter chain before exiting the application.